# Lambda Expression: How to map to a List rather than IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

I am using the following code to avoid repetition:

```
 private static Expression<Func<Incident_Log, IncidentVM>> mappingIncidentVM()
        {
            return x => new IncidentVM
            {
                incident_ID = x.incident_id,                    
                incident_description = x.incident_description,
                file_names = x.file_names,
                location = x.location,

                Actions = 
                    x.Action_Log.Where(y => y.assigned_to == y.assigned_to).Select(z => new ActionVM
                {
                    incident_ID = z.incident_id,
                    action_ID = z.action_id,
                    action_description = z.action_description

                })                   
                //actionList = new List<ActionVM>(d => mappingActionVM)

            };
        }
```

Then I can do the following:

`List<IncidentVM> incidents = db.Incident_Log.Select(mappingIncidentVM).ToList();`

And it maps the Incident_Log entity to my viewModel IncidentVM. 
My problem is that I wish I could map directly to a list rather than an IEnumerable.Something like this:

```
  private static Expression<Func<Incident_Log, IncidentVM>> mappingIncidentVM()
        {
            return x => new IncidentVM
            {
                incident_ID = x.incident_id,                   
                incident_description = x.incident_description,
                file_names = x.file_names,
                location = x.location,

                actionList =
                    x.Action_Log.Where(y => y.assigned_to == y.assigned_to).Select(z => new ActionVM
                    {
                        incident_ID = z.incident_id,
                        action_ID = z.action_id,
                        action_description = z.action_description

                    }).ToList()


            };
        }
```

But that is throwing an error:

`LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method System.Collections.Generic.List[ViewModel.ActionVM] ToList[ActionVM](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable([ViewModel.ActionVM]) method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

The ToList() is not recognised.

Here is my ViewModel:

```
 public class IncidentVM
    {

        public int incident_ID { set; get; }               

        [Display(Name = "Description*")]
        [Required]
        public string incident_description { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Specific Location*")]
        [Required]
        public string location { set; get; }

        public string file_names { set; get; }

//Here is the problem, I 'd like to have only actionList
        public IEnumerable<ActionVM> Actions { get; set; }          
        public List<ActionVM> actionList { get; set; }
```

And here is the model for the Action_Log Object:

```
public partial class Action_Log
{
    public int action_id { get; set; }
    public int incident_id { get; set; }
    public string action_description { get; set; }

    public virtual Incident_Log Incident_Log { get; set; }       
}
```

Is it possible to map directly to a List in this case?

Comment: `y.assigned_to == y.assigned_to`?

Comment: Is Action_Log implementing IQueryable in the other part of your partial class? How are you performing a Query on it otherwise? Can you edit the OP to show the other part of the partial class?

Comment: @GertArnold I took some properties away from the model to shorten the code...assigned_to was one of them (just a string)

Comment: You cannot call `.Where()` on a class which doesn't implement IQueryable. Is there not another part of this class defined somewhere else (that does implement IQueryable)?

Comment: @ThomasCook I don't know where to find the other part of the partial class. I am using DB first, the model classes (incl. Action_Log) are auto-generqted from the DB.

Comment: Ah right, is this your part of the code though? I mean maybe someone else defined the other part somewhere else? Do a ctr+f and search the solution for "partial class Action_Log" and see if you get another partial?

Comment: @ThomasCook The code above works to populate the IEnumerable Action property, but I can't make it work to populate the actionList (List) property

Comment: @ThomasCook No I couldn't find another partial Action_Log.

Comment: Yea but your error is on calling `ToList()` on the IQueryable object of type `Action_Log`.

Comment: Yes and as pointed out by @Servy the query provider is not able to generate this into SQL

Comment: Yea but ToList isn't part of the query is it? I thought that enumerated the query results?

Comment: It is part of the second implementation of mappingIncidentVM, the one that throw an error.

Comment: Can you not do this:  `db.Incident_Log.Include("Action_List").ToList().Select( mappingIncidentVM).ToList();`...that first ToList() will materialise so now the ToList() in the Func you passed will not be operating on an IQueryable.
Otherwise you cannot do this because the IQueryable implementation for your database will insist on trying to translate that ToList() into SQL, which will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that LINQ cannot translate `ToList` so just go for the `IEnumerable` and then use `ToList` when working on local data (after you have executed the query) and you should be fine.

Comment: The question is *specifically* asking how to *avoid* the need to materialize the inner query to a list after the outer query has been executed, and specifically mentions that it's what they're currently doing.

Comment: the 2nd part of the answer states that LINQ cannt do that. Or am I wrong? @Servy

Comment: The question states that they got an error in their attempt to do it, and they want to know how to correct that problem and allow it to actually work.

Comment: @Servy the only possibility is to load the rows in memory first with `ToList` or `AsEnumerable` and then use `ToList`, it cannot be done that way

Comment: @Sid so I can get the IEnumerable starigh away, but not a List?

Comment: @Sychal no you can't. I am quite confident you can't do that without making some custom extention/implementation. But it seems like Servy knows something I don't so I hope he gets back to you with some info!

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
actionList =
      x.Action_Log.Where(y => y.assigned_to == y.assigned_to).Select(z => new ActionVM
      {
          incident_ID = z.incident_id,
          action_ID = z.action_id,
          action_description = z.action_description

       }).ToList<ActionVM>()
```

Comment: That's not going to change anything.  The problem is not that the generic type argument can't be inferred, the error is that the query provider can't translate it.

Comment: I just tried this, but I am getting the same error.

Comment: Don't we need to know the type of `Action_Log` then?

Comment: @Servy Is there anyway to do it then? Or should I just stick with the IEnumerable?

Comment: @ThomasCook I just added the Action_Log class